# Problems in catching these exceptions in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 5, `App::missing` and `App::error` is not available, so how do i catch exceptions and missing pages now?

I could not find any information regarding this in the documentation.

Comment: @Ivanka It's nearly a copy-and-paste exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 5.3 you use the [exception handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#the-exception-handler) that is found in `App\Exceptions\Handler`.

The handler has two methods `report()` and `render()`. Render is responsible for what you're looking for. This method is used to render exceptions in the format you require. The given example is:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
        return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

The documentation has much more detail on how to handle different exceptions that are thrown by the framework.